# How can I create a notification which pops up on home screen at a regular time?

Tags: android

I want to create a notification system which popsup on home screen and a text is shown. If we click on the notification the app is shown on the foreground. This notification must be poped at a given time period.Is this possible help plz?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule your notifications using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Basically, you can either specify a specific datetime or specify a period between two different notifications.

If you want the notifications to be shown on the Home screen, may be you should consider developing a [Widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) which will be less intrusive and will be more Androidy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer in ur notification

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        triggerNotification();//ur notification
    }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, task);
```

also for refrenece go thru: [UI Updates](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)